p5.js on OpenProcessing, sketch using audio works on desktop but not on mobile
Good afternoon all;
Forgive me as I am very much a 'bodger' when it comes to coding so would appreciate your patience with my noviceness!  I have made a rough sketch oppr.org/s/twgjO43M on OpenProcessing (and have also pasted the code below) where the code works perfectly on desktop but not on mobile.  In short, it is an audio player where you can upload an audio file and then based on a dropdown menu and sliders, you can change the playback rate of the audio file.  I use this in my dance courses in case I want to use an audio file at a different tempo or if I want to train my students in working with variable tempos (i.e., erratic tempos to train their sense of timing) throughout a choreography.
My specific issues are:

When I use desktop and run developer tools as if I were running a phone or tablet, the code works, but when I use an actual phone or tablet I get a "Media play method encountered an unexpected error" notice in my console.

When I use the developer tools to run the code as if I were running a phone or tablet, I have to press and hold the buttons for at least a second to make it work (I think this is the 300ms thing that happens with phones and tablets?).  How might I address this?

Though it works 'perfectly' on desktop, there is one quirk where I cannot press the 'Upload File' button without first clicking somewhere on the canvas first!


I'm actually only concerned for the 1st point where I want the program to be able to work on students' and my phones / tablets, whereas the 2nd and 3rd point are just inconveniences.  Thanks for any help that anyone can provide!
let audioPlayer;
let playStatus = false;
let fileInput;
let fileName = '';
let currentTime = 0;
let totalDuration = 1; // Placeholder, will be updated when the track is loaded

let isDragging = false;
let dragOffsetX = 0;
let dragOffsetY = 0;

let circleX, circleY, displaySpeed;

let nunitoFont;

OPC.slider({
    name: 'speed',
    value: 1,
    min: 0.50,
    max: 2.01,
    step: 0.01,
    label: 'Speed',
    description: 'Changes the initial speed of the track'
});

OPC.slider({
    name: 'volume',
    value: 0.5,
    min: 0,
    max: 1.05,
    step: 0.05,
    label: 'Volume',
    description: 'Volume adjustment'
});

OPC.slider({
    name: 'seedNum',
    value: 536,
    min: 0,
    max: 2024,
    step: 1,
    label: 'Seed',
    description: 'Randomizes the Peaks & Valleys graph'
});

OPC.button('playTrack', 'Play');
OPC.button('stopTrack', 'Stop');
OPC.button({
    name: 'uploadTrack',
    value: 'Upload Track',
    description: 'Upload button not working? Try clicking the centre of the canvas and then the button.'
});

OPC.select({
    name: 'graphType',
    label: 'Graph',
    options: {
        "Stable": 0,
        "Accelerated": 1,
        "Decelerated": 2,
        "Peaks & Valleys": 3
    },
    value: 0,
    description: 'Choose speed graph'
});

function preload() {
    nunitoFont = loadFont('./Nunito-Regular.ttf');
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    textFont(nunitoFont);

    // Create p5.js file input button and then hide it.
    // OP Configurator 3000 button will trigger this button.
    // Need to fix this circuitous route.
    fileInput = createFileInput(handleFile);
    fileInput.position(10, 10);
    fileInput.hide();
    fileInput.style('opacity', '0');
    fileInput.style('width', '1px');
    fileInput.style('height', '1px');
    // Initialize audio player
    audioPlayer = createAudio();
    audioPlayer.elt.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        totalDuration = audioPlayer.duration();
    });
}

function draw() {
    background(55); // Clear the background
    fill(255);
    audioPlayer.volume(volume);

    if (fileName) {
        let baseTextSize = 32;
        textSize(baseTextSize);
        textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);

        // Measure the width of the text
        let measuredTextWidth = textWidth(fileName);

        // Adjust the text size if it exceeds the width of the screen
        while (measuredTextWidth > width * 0.9) { // 90% of screen width as padding
            baseTextSize -= 1; // Decrease text size
            textSize(baseTextSize);
            measuredTextWidth = textWidth(fileName); // Update measurement
        }

        // Draw the text in the center of the canvas
        text(fileName, width / 2, height / 4);

        // Display the adjusted current time and total duration
        textSize(16);
        let currentMinutes = floor(currentTime / 60);
        let currentSeconds = floor(currentTime % 60);
        let totalMinutes = floor(totalDuration / 60);
        let totalSeconds = floor(totalDuration % 60);
        let timeString = nf(currentMinutes, 2) + ':' + nf(currentSeconds, 2) + ' / ' + nf(totalMinutes, 2) + ':' + nf(totalSeconds, 2);
        text(timeString, width / 2, height / 4 + 40);
    }
    noStroke();
    rect(0, height / 2, width, height / 2); // Graph screen set up on the bottom half of the screen
    fill(0, 150);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    stroke(100, 30)
    line(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, width * 0.5, height); // Sets up a vertical line at centre of the speed graph.
    stroke(100, 105);
    textSize(12);
    if (graphType != 3) { // Sets up a horizontal centre line in the speed graph.
        text("SPEED SETTING LINE", width * 0.5, height * 0.75);
        line(0, height * 0.75, width, height * 0.75);
    } else { // Case 3 has a different centre line as it goes from 0.50 min to 2.00 max, whereas other cases go from 0.0 to 2.00
        text("SPEED SETTING LINE", width * 0.5, height * 0.833);
        line(0, height * 0.833, width, height * 0.833);
    }

    currentTime = audioPlayer.time(); // Keeps track of current time in the uploaded audio player

    // Adjust speed based on the selected graphType
    switch (graphType) {
        case 0: // Stable -- maintains the tempo of the file according to the speed set
            audioPlayer.speed(speed);
            stroke(5, 89, 137);
            line(0, height / 2 + height / 4, width, height / 2 + height / 4); // Draw horizontal line
            circleX = map(currentTime, 0, totalDuration, 0, width);
            circleY = height / 2 + height / 4; // Keep circle vertical position constant
            displaySpeed = speed;
            break;
        case 1: // Accelerated -- gradually increases speed to 2.00x over the length of the track
            let accelSpeed = speed + (2 * speed - speed) * (currentTime / totalDuration);
            audioPlayer.speed(accelSpeed);
            stroke(5, 89, 137);
            line(0, height / 2 + height / 4, width, height / 2); // Draw angled line upwards from centre
            circleX = map(currentTime, 0, totalDuration, 0, width);
            circleY = map(currentTime, 0, totalDuration, height / 2 + height / 4, height / 2);
            displaySpeed = accelSpeed;
            break;
        case 2: // Decelerated -- gradually decreases speed to 0.00x over the length of the track. May require reset of program after it hits 0.
            let decelSpeed = speed - (speed - 0.5 * speed) * (currentTime / totalDuration);
            audioPlayer.speed(decelSpeed);
            stroke(5, 89, 137);
            line(0, height / 2 + height / 4, width, height); // Draw angled line downwards from centre
            circleX = map(currentTime, 0, totalDuration, 0, width);
            circleY = map(currentTime, 0, totalDuration, height / 2 + height / 4, height);
            displaySpeed = decelSpeed;
            break;
        case 3: // Peaks & Valleys -- creates a mountainous speed for the track.
            stroke(5, 89, 137);
            noFill();
            var speedRand = seedNum;
            noiseSeed(speedRand);
            beginShape();
            let xoff = 0;
            let yValues = [];
            for (let x = 0; x <= width; x += 10) {
                let y = constrain(map(noise(xoff), 0.25, 0.75, height, height / 2), height / 2, height); // sets the Y-axis of the graph
                vertex(x, y);
                yValues.push(y);
                xoff += 0.05;
            }
            endShape();
            // Tracks tempo according to the mountainous line generated
            let index = map(currentTime, 0, totalDuration, 0, yValues.length - 1);
            let lowerIndex = Math.floor(index);
            let upperIndex = Math.ceil(index);
            let t = index - lowerIndex;
            circleY = lerp(yValues[lowerIndex], yValues[upperIndex], t);
            circleX = map(currentTime, 0, totalDuration, 0, width);

            let minSpeed = 0.5 * speed;
            let maxSpeed = 2 * speed;
            let contourSpeed = map(circleY, height, height / 2, minSpeed, maxSpeed);

            audioPlayer.speed(contourSpeed);
            displaySpeed = contourSpeed;
            break;
    }

    stroke(200, 8, 21);
    fill(200, 8, 21);
    ellipse(circleX, circleY, 10, 10); // a helpful little circle that shows where in the graph you are.

    // Check if the mouse is hovering over the circle
    let d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, circleX, circleY);
    if (d < 5) {
        cursor('pointer'); // HANDS cursor
    } else {
        cursor(ARROW); // Default pointy cursor
    }

    noStroke();
    textSize(12);
    textAlign(LEFT, CENTER);
    text(nf(displaySpeed, 1, 2) + 'x SPEED', circleX, circleY + 15); // displays text next to the circle to show current speed.
}

function buttonPressed(trackControls) {
    if (trackControls !== 'uploadTrack' && !fileName) {
        alert('Please upload a file before playing or stopping.');
        return;
    }

    if (trackControls === 'playTrack') {
        if (!playStatus) {
            audioPlayer.loop(); // or audioPlayer.play();
            OPC.button('playTrack', 'Pause');
            playStatus = true;
        } else {
            audioPlayer.pause();
            OPC.button('playTrack', 'Play');
            playStatus = false;
        }
    }

    if (trackControls === 'stopTrack') {
        audioPlayer.stop();
        OPC.button('playTrack', 'Play');
        playStatus = false;
    }

    if (trackControls === 'uploadTrack') {
        fileInput.elt.click();
        OPC.button('playTrack', 'Play');
        playStatus = false;
    }
}

function handleFile(file) {
    if (file.type === 'audio') {
        audioPlayer.src = file.data;
        fileName = file.name;
    } else {
        alert('Not a valid audio file!');
        fileName = '';
    }
}

// Mouse and touch event handlers for dragging the circle
function mousePressed() {
    handlePress(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function mouseDragged() {
    handleDrag(mouseX, mouseY);
}

function mouseReleased() {
    isDragging = false;
}

function touchStarted() {
    if (touches.length > 0) {
        handlePress(touches[0].x, touches[0].y);
    }
    return false;
}

function touchMoved() {
    if (touches.length > 0) {
        handleDrag(touches[0].x, touches[0].y);
    }
    return false;
}

function touchEnded() {
    isDragging = false;
    return false;
}

function handlePress(x, y) {
    // Check if the mouse or touch is pressed within the circle
    let d = dist(x, y, circleX, circleY);
    if (d < 10) {
        isDragging = true;
        dragOffsetX = x - circleX;
        dragOffsetY = y - circleY;
    }
}

function handleDrag(x, y) {
    if (isDragging) {
        // Update the circle's position based on mouse or touch movement
        circleX = x - dragOffsetX;
        circleY = y - dragOffsetY;
        circleX = constrain(circleX, 0, width);
        circleY = constrain(circleY, height / 2, height);
        currentTime = map(circleX, 0, width, 0, totalDuration);
        audioPlayer.time(currentTime);
    }
}

// For desktop and switching between portrait and landscape on phones / tablets
function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

